# javascript - Get headers hash while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

I have a page with multiple headers (h1,h2,h3). I need to get header ID and put it in URL as hash while I scroll through the page.

Example code below.

```
<div>
  <h1 id="random_numbers_here"> 
    <p> lorem ipsum </p>
  <h1 id="random_numbers_here"> 
    <p> lorem ipsum </p>
  <h2 id="random_numbers_here"> 
    <p> lorem ipsum </p>
  <h3 id="random_numbers_here"> 
    <p> lorem ipsum </p>
  <h3 id="random_numbers_here"> 
    <p> lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

My JS code:

```
$('.page').on('scroll',(function(){
    var winTop = $('.page').scrollTop();
    var h1 = $('h1');
    var h2 = $('h2');
    var h3 = $('h3');

    $(h1).each(function(){
        console.log(
        $(this).offset().top < winTop +10 
        && $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > winTop + 10);
    })
}));
```

When my "header detector" will work ill just $(this).attr('id') and use window.location.hash to put it in URL.

But it gives me true or false on wrong headers. On h2 it returns true while im at h3.

I have no idea how to make this work.